# input and output for the same variable

Tags: angular, angular5, getter-setter

I have a variable that can be edited from parent and for child.

parent.html:

```
 <div *ngIf="editEnabled">
  <mat-icon (click)="disableEdit()">cancel</mat-icon>
</div>

<child [(editEnabled)]="editEnabled"></child>
```

parent.ts:

```
export class ParentComponent {

   editEnabled: boolean;

   disableEdit(){
     this.editEnabled = false;
   }
}
```

Child.html:

```
 <div *ngIf="!editEnabled">
  <mat-icon (click)="enableEdit()">settings</mat-icon>
</div>
```

child.ts

```
private _editEnabled: boolean;

@Input()
 set editEnabled(value: boolean) {
  this._editEnabled = value;

}
get editEnabled(): boolean {
 return this._editEnabled;
}

enableEdit(){
     this.editEnabled = true;
}
```

But I cant comunicate editEnabled between the two components.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction should help you getting started.

Comment: you must use output decerator in this case

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When defining a double-binded variable, you will need to define one @Input-decorator with the variable name:

```
@Input() editEnabled: boolean;
```

and one @Output-decorator with the variable name and `Change` after it, because this one emits the changing-event of the variable:

```
@Output() editEnabledChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Then when changing the variable inside the child component, invoke `this.editEnabledChange.emit(true)`. Your double binding with `[(...)]` is correct!

Comment: this pattern is weird to my taste. What if we need to climb one more component up to grandparent ? Are we going to have editEnabledChangeChange ?

Comment: No, you still have „editEnabled“ with a double binding.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would be curious to see an example of an event climbing up up several components, I need to investigate on that.

Comment: This is in the official documentation https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

Comment: The docs say:
"For two-way data binding to work, the @Output() property must use the pattern, inputChange, where input is the name of the @Input() property. For example, if the @Input() property is size, the @Output() property must be sizeChange."

So Giacomo means literally add "Change" to the end of the variable name of your Output var. It's looking for an Output that has the same name as the Input but with the added "Change" to it. Anything else such as "editEnabledEvent" will not work and result in: 
"Can't bind to [(editEnabled)] since it is not provided by any applicable directives."

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to add the `editEnabledChange`-Emitter every time you change the variable `correct` you can write:

```js
_correct: boolean;
@Input()
set correct(val: boolean) {
  this.correctChange.emit(val);
  this._correct = val;
}
get correct() {
  return this._correct;
}
@Output()
correctChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

```html
<app-pin [(correct)]="isPinCorrect"></app-pin>
```

Comment: Can you or someone make a new annotation that implements this, so that we can just write @InputOutput() correct: boolean; ???

Comment: No, there's no straightforward way in Angular to declare and use an input/output field in a component